# Apply a common criteria to all Spring JPA repository methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

### What we're trying to achieve?

Spring Data JPA lets us define repository methods like this:

```java
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
```

With that, the query to be run will be figured out with the method name. In this case, something like `select * from user where email = ?`.

We want to apply an additional common criteria to *all* such `find...By` methods on the repository, a `and deleted_at is null` condition.

Essentially, `findByEmail` should behave like `findByEmailAndDeletedAtNull`.

### Why?

We used to do this with reactive Spring Data MongoDB by extending `ReactivePartTreeMongoQuery`, and overriding `createQuery` with something like this:

```java
    @Override
    protected Mono<Query> createQuery(ConvertingParameterAccessor accessor) {
        return super.createQuery(accessor).map(query -> {
            query.addCriteria(where("deletedAt").is(null));
            return query;
        });
    }
```

This worked well. We're now moving to using an RDBMS and looking for similar behavior there.

### What have we tried?

I found that `PartTreeJpaQuery.QueryPreparer.createQuery()` is the one that calls `EntityManager.createQuery` off a `CriteriaQuery` object, and returns a `TypedQuery` object.

I managed to hook into the middle of this But can't add additional conditions to the `TypedQuery` object, like I can with `CriteriaQuery`. And there's no way to access the `QueryPreparer` object either to hook into it.

I can't extend `PartTreeJpaQuery` class either, because it doesn't have any public constructors.

Is there any way to do this at all?

Comment: I see the downvote and vote-to-close. May I know what details I can add to this please?

Comment: I agree, people should seriously comment their thoughts or reasons while downvoting

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Optional<User> findByEmailAndDeletedAt(String email, DateTime deletedAt);
```

And call it using

```
repo.findByEmailAndDeletedAt(email, null);
```

Another approach is to use a Discriminator to differ between two Entities:

1. User
2. DeletedUser

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772370) how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for way to have the `deletedAt` condition be implicitly applied to _all_ repository methods, even if the method is named `findByEmail`. I've detailed this in the question text. Let me know if there's anything I can elaborate.